# Having trouble with PHP code to populate a form from three tables and only if records are in one specific table (registrations table)

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error. I am including the whole code, for the page. Hopefully someone smarter than I am can help and or give helpful hints. It's beginner code, I'm trying to learn.

```
Here's the error:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound    variables does not match number of tokens in    C:\xampp\htdocs\4090_TamezP_Lab05\tech_support\incident_manager\incident_form.php:70 Stack trace: #0    C:\xampp\htdocs\4090_TamezP_Lab05\tech_support\incident_manager\incident_form.php(70): PDOStatement-   >execute() #1 {main} thrown in   C:\xampp\htdocs\4090_TamezP_Lab05\tech_support\incident_manager\incident_form.php on line 70

Line 70 is the one in the middle 
$statement->bindvalue(':email', $email);
$statement->execute();
$customers=$statement->fetchALL();
```

```
<?php include_once '../view/header.php'; ?>
<?php require('../model/database.php');?>

<?php

// Variable Declarations

$customerID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'customerID');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$productCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'productCode');

// set default value of title and description variables for initial page load for input validation

if (!isset($title)) { $title = ''; }
if (!isset($description)) { $description = ''; }

// Validation to check for blank email

if ($email == '')
{   
$error = 'Email cannot be blank. Please enter a valid email.';
//require_once('../errors/error.php');  
require_once('index.php');
exit();
}

/*
Query customers table to select customer id, first name, last name and email based on the email entered        into the Text Box on the index.php file

Note:   This query will return a single record and the value of the email is passed to the     register_form.php page using the
    Text Box name which is "email"
*/   

$query1 = 'SELECT customerID, firstName, lastName, email FROM customers WHERE email = :email';
$statement1 = $db->prepare($query1);
$statement1->bindValue(':email', $email);
$statement1->execute();
$customer = $statement1->fetch();
$statement1->closeCursor();

$customer_id = $customer['customerID'];

// Validation to check that email exists

if ($customer == NULL)
{
$error = 'No matching email. Please enter a valid email.';
//require_once('../errors/error.php');
require_once('index.php');
exit();
}

/*
Query the customers, registrations, and products table to select the product code and product name from the products table for only the registered products for the selected customer's email.
Order the results by the product code. This query is using the INNER JOIN to join three tables. See page 104, How to select data from multiple tables. Example code for joining three tables is provided.
Especially notice the order in which the tables are joined.

Note:   This query may return zero to many values representing all the products matching the customer's email. The drop-down list should display the product name, but pass the product code.
*/

/* INSERT CODE HERE FOR QUERY DESCRIBED ABOVE*/
$query = 'SELECT products.name, registrations.customerID, registrations.productCode
        FROM customers
        INNER JOIN registrations
        ON customers.customerID = registrations.customerID
        INNER JOIN products
        ON products.productCode = registrations.productCode';           
$statement=$db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindvalue(':email', $email);
$statement->execute();
$customers=$statement->fetchALL();
$statement->closeCursor();

?>

<main>
<h2>Create Incident</h2>

    <p></p>    
    <form action="incident_added.php" method="post" id="aligned">            
        <input type="hidden" name="customerID"
            value="<?php echo $customer['customerID']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email"
            value="<?php echo $customer['email']; ?>">

        <label>Customer:</label><?php echo $customer['firstName'] . ' ' . $customer['lastName']; ?><br>

        <label>Product:</label>
        
        <select name="productCode">
            <!--INSERT CODE HERE TO POPULATE DROP-DOWN LIST WITH PRODUCT NAME AND CAPTURE PRODUCT CODE-->
            
            <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($product['name']); ?>">
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($product['productCode']); ?>
            </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>                
        </select> <br>  
        
        <label>Title:</label><input type="text" name="title"
            value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($title);?>"><br> <!-- so that the user does not need to reenter valid title entry -->
        <label>Description:</label><textarea id="description" name="description" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $description;?></textarea><br>
        <!-- so that the user does not need to reenter valid description entry -->  
        
        <?php if (!empty($error)) { ?>
            <p class="error"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($error); ?></p>
        <?php } ?>  
        
        <input type="submit" value="Create Incident" /><br>         
    </form>

</main>

<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>


        
        
<?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $product['productCode']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['version']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['releaseDate'] ?></td>
        <td><form action="delete_product.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_code"
                value="<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete">
        </form></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm just a beginner so I'm not sure I've tried all there is to try. I've looked back at everything I know us. And I can't figure it out.

Comment: why you are binding $statement->bindvalue(':email', $email); at line 70 ?

Comment: you didn't use `:email` in your `$query` ... so why do you `$statement->bindvalue(':email', $email);`  ... Delete it?

Comment: Deleting it got rid of the error. Thank You